# TypeError: Cannot find function getFrom in object GmailMessage

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace

I have the following function in Google Apps Script:

```
function getMail() {
   var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 50);
   var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads); 
   var froms = [];
   for (var i=0; i<messages.length; i++) {
       var msg = messages[i];
       Logger.log(msg.getFrom());
   }
}
```

getMessagesForThreads returns a list of GmailMessage objects.
So why can't it access the getFrom method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getMail() {
    var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 50);
    var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads); 
    for (var i=0; i<messages.length; i++) {
        for (var j=0; j<messages[i].length; j++) {
            Logger.log(messages[i][j].getFrom());
        }
    }
}
```

`getMessagesForThreads` returns `GmailMessage[][]` not a `GmailMessage[]` like I had thought.